# is it possible to fix a java script error from an external script

Tags: javascript

i use an external script from Air-bnb. The script causes an error in Internet Explorer. For Air bnb it is not possible to fix this script. Is there a possibility to fix it by my self?

This function is not supported by IE

```
if(c.includes(r))return t
```

On this site i load the script via iframe:

https://www.immvestwolf.de/rent-a-home-2

i look forward to find a solution...

Thanks

Comment: @Ravenous The scripts are loaded using iFrames and not page loaded in iFrame.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment. this was it: How can polyfills in his page affect JavaScript in a iframe without CORS support?

Comment: And yes, but how do you expect the top page (the one in which the iframe is loaded) to affect JavaScript sandboxed in an iframe (which does whatever, can display page, can include scripts)? The reason it is like that is because they care about security.

Comment: @Ravenous The scripts are loaded using iFrame. There is no page in iFrame. There is a mechanism (*can't remember name now*), which is used to communicate between servers and get resources and avoid CORS. So essentially, scripts are executed in your page and not in iFrame. So adding polyfills should do it.

Comment: 'get resources between services' is what CORS means, and loading scripts in my page via an iframe is terrible, the security bit falls under both sides, I won't allow another origin to inject their JavaScript on my site, be it Facebook or Google.

Answer (score 1):

No. If they don't support IE, it's their decision and the iframe is a different context that won't affect the JavaScript running in the top/parent context (your page).

You can exclude the iframe from IE and have IE users go directly to Airbnb for the specific set of actions you want them to go through.

Comment: I think Edge is more than enough in 2018.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. If you use an iframe to load external content there is absolute no way to manipulate or react.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can.

Issue is `.includes` is a part of ES6 features and belongs to String and Array. These features are not supported by IE. If you include the polyfills, it should work.

#### References:

- [Array.includes MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Polyfill)
- [String.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Polyfill)

**Note:** Polyfills should be added on the page that is having issues and not on parent/root page

Comment: That means Airbnb needs to fix the script which they won't. And although the error is thrown for that, there might be a lot of other missing ES6 features that they'd have to come up with polyfills for (which is probably why they refused to "fix" the script).

Comment: @Ravenous If there is any issues in a lib, you can either use patches to fix them or use another library. If you think there are many features that might throw issues, you can also use `babel-polyfill`. That adds most of the polyfills. Also saying **No** is wrong as there is a way. So I guess I'll keep my answer as it is correct.

Comment: I didnt downvote your answer. It would have been correct if the author of the question wouldnt have mentioned 'for Airbnb it is not possible to fix the script'.

Comment: @Ravenous I don't care about votes. We all are here to learn and I'm sharing little information that I have. If someone feels it is incorrect, they have all rights to downvote. A comment would have helped but none the less, it does not mean its wrong. So I'll keep my answer. If it helps anyone in any way, vote is worth. Have a good day :-)